# Different versions between local and remote git repo - how to syncronize again?

Tags: git

I have a post-update hook like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo “**** Pulling changes into Dev [Hub’s post-update hook]”
echo
case “ $1 ” in
*‘refs/heads/dev’*)
cd /home/user/www/dev/ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub dev
echo
echo “Dev was pulled”
echo
;;
esac
```

Git is telling me that the local and remote are up to date, but they aren't. 
Local is a more recent version then the remote.

**When I git pull I get:**

> Already up-to-date.

**When I do a git status on the REMOTE I get:**

> On branch dev nothing to commit (working directory clean)

(previously, when doing git status on REMOTE I've seen that a file (.htaccess one) was not added, so remotely I did, `git add .` and `git commit -a -m "added htaccess remotely"`, they I did `git pull` locally, but I still get: Already up-to-date.)

I've tried to change something locally (in hope that it would pushed that specific change and all the other changes previously done) - no luck.

Can anyone help me to get all repos synchronized again ?

```
git remote -v
```

> hub   ssh://user@site.org/home/user/private/repos/site_hub.git (fetch)
>
> hub   ssh://user@site.org/home/user/private/repos/site_hub.git (push)

hub is a bare repo.

Comment: To tell the story short, can we force to push all local changes on the remote no matter what? :)

Comment: what are the remote adress? I mean what shows `git remove -v`. Then first fetch the changes `git fetch origin`. Let's what happen

Comment: @FatihArslan updated my question with git remote results

Comment: Hm, maybe youre pulling from wrong branch. On which branch are you at local? You can list remote branches via `git branch -r`. Maybe `git pull hub correct_branch` will solve it?

Comment: @FatihArslan I end up re-changing and re-pushing the files that were edited before the conflict. All seems to go well now.

Comment: @All despite this being solved, on future cases, I believe editing the files again would be a proper way for solving this sort of conflict due to a file that was not properly updated and the thing refuses to pull hence, resulting on different versions, I believe. If anyone has a proper answer about what to do, on those "like" situations, I would be glad to mark it as answer.